# Get HTML tag from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, string

What is the best and cleanest way of getting a html tag from a string?

I have a string of html with several embed tags containing videos. There can be any number of embed tag in the html string

I guess i could do something like this but it can't be the best way:

```
string embedSrc = propertyText.Substring(propertyText.IndexOf("<embed"), (propertyText.IndexOf  ("</embed") - propertyText.IndexOf("<embed") + 8));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse it easily. If not you could use a regular expression

Comment: Thanks but the project put in my hands run on .Net 2.0 and HtmlAgilityPack need 3.5.

Comment: @Andy, from the link I posted: `the version posted here on CodePlex is for the .NET Framework 2.0. If you need the old version, please go to the old page or drop me a note. `

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use C# api for this. Try using XmlDocument's LoadXml(string) method. After that just use the object operations to extract inner tags or texts from it. Take a look at
[XmlDocument from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx)

Comment: I tryed this but get the error that my html document has multiple root elements.

Comment: Make shure your html is well formed and that you are passing the correct root tag:
Correct
    
'    <tag>
        some text
    </tag>
'
Incorrect (this throws multiple roots)
    
    <tag>
        some text
    </tag>
    <tag>
        another text
    </tag>

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian has the right of it, find a library and the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is a great option.  If you need the document structure, this is really the best option.

Parsing with Regular Expressions is generally considered a no-no for HTML.  It really depends on what you're trying to read out of the input string.  I wrote a [lightweight xml/html parser using Regex](http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Html/XmlLightParser.cs) just to see it done.  This can provide you with the Regex patterns needed.